# reading a file that doesn't exist

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I have got a small program that prints the contents of files using the system call - read.

```
unsigned char buffer[8];
size_t offset=0;
size_t bytes_read;

int i;

int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

do{
    bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("0x%06x : ", offset);

    for(i=0; i<bytes_read; ++i)
    {
        printf("%c ", buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    offset = offset + bytes_read;
}while(bytes_read == sizeof(buffer));
```

Now while running I give a file name that doesn't exist.
It prints some kind of data mixed with environment variables and a segmentation fault at the end.

How is this possible? What is the program printing?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Please see my answer, which addresses the question you actually asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

read is returning -1 because fd is invalid, you store that in bytes_read which is of type size_t which is unsigned, so your loop prints (size_t)-1 chars, which is a very large number, much larger than the size of buffer. So, you're printing a big chunk of your address space and then getting a segfault when you eventually reach the end and access an invalid address.

As others have mentioned (without answering your actual question), you should be checking the results of open for an error. e.g.,

```
int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
if( fd < 0 ){
    fprintf(stderr, "error opening %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

A caveat: if you do another system call, or call any routine that might do a system call (e.g., printf) before calling strerror, you must save errno and then pass the saved copy to strerror.

Another note about your program:

```
while(bytes_read == sizeof(buffer))
```

This is not a good test, because read can return less than the amount you ask for. Your loop should continue until read returns <= 0.

Comment: Thanks Jim. It couldn't have been explained better.

Answer (score 7):

It's printing rubbish because `fd` will invariably be set to -1 which is not a good thing to pass to `read` since it will, in turn do nothing other than return -1 as well. It will leave your buffer untouched meaning that it's holding whatever rubbish you had in there when you started.

You could probably put the entire `do` loop inside something like:

```
if (fd == -1) {
    printf ("error here");
} else {
    // do loop here
}
```

Comment: Ah, but buffer is only 8 bytes long which is not enough for "some kind of data mixed with environment variables", and reading it should not cause a segfault. It takes a wee bit more thought and examination of the code to grasp why the program is doing what it's doing ... see my answer.

Comment: That's good extra analysis, @Jim, however, it doesn't change the fact that the root cause of _all_ the problems is the fact that OP is ignoring the error conditions. Both the return values from _open_ and _read_ should be checked for -1. With proper error checking, all the problems disappear.

Comment: Everything you say is true, but _it doesn't answer the OP's question_, which was how the program could do what it does. Odds are that the OP already realized that he should have checked the return from open, since he knows the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Jim:  I'll give you an upvote for the extra analysis but, for "How is this possible? What is the program printing?", I think I answered that pretty well, though I'm biased of course :-) The problem was lack of error checking. Fix that and the problem disappears.

Comment: We all know what the problem and solution are, but again that is not an answer to the question, and it takes more than "bias" not to see or acknowledge that.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check that the file descriptor returned by `open` is valid before using it. As per [these docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html), you should get a non-negative response for a valid file. Reading from an invalid descriptor is likely the source of your problem.

Comment: Reading from an invalid file descriptor returns -1. A careful examination of the program reveals why that results in the observed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Upon successful completion, open function shall open the file and return a non-negative integer representing the file descriptor. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error. So please check fd before entering the loop to perform the read.

Comment: That's good advice but it doesn't answer the question that was asked.